# XPath: OR in the middle or in the end of xpath not working

Tags: xpath

XPath OR(|) in the middle or in the end does not work. For example,

```
//div//(div | span)
//div(//div | //span)
```

Error: Invalid xpath.

The following works:

```
//div//div | //div//span
```

Tried with Chrome console(XPath 1.0, I believe).